Can I create a UFS1 or UFS2 partition in Ubuntu?
I want to create two partitions, one in UFS1 and another in UFS2. I try to install ufsutils:
sudo apt install ufsutils

But there is no such a package.
I try to invoke
mkfs.ufs

It said command not found.
I am using ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64

Try: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/87312045/ufsutils_8.2-3_amd64.deb

Please edit the question and add the actual Ubuntu version info.

@David, I have added it. Thanks
